# función click en un id con JavaScript dentro de un while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Buenas Amigos tengo un problema al ejecutar un script dentro de un While.
los id se repiten y me generan un error, trate de solucionarlo concatenando un contador a cada id pero no me funciona dejo código.

```html
<?php
   while ($rowMP = $sqlMP->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id = $rowMP['id'];
     $IdCom = 'IdCom';
     $CerrCom = 'CerrCom';
     $ConCom = 'ConCom';
     $idValue = $IdCom.$id;
     $idCerr = $CerrCom.$id;
     $idConC = $ConCom.$id; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  IdCom = "<?php echo $idValue; ?>";
  CerrCom = "<?php echo $idCerr; ?>";
  ConCom = "<?php echo $idConC; ?>";

  $('#'+IdCom).click(function() {
    document.getElementById(ConCom).style.display = "block";
  });
  $('#'+CerrCom).click(function() {
    document.getElementById(ConCom).style.display = "none";
  });
</script>

<i class="icon-comment-6" id="<?php echo $idValue; ?>"></i>

<div class="coment" style="display: none;" id="<?php echo $idConC; ?>">
  <p>div a mostrar</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

El punto es que deseo ejecutar una función en cada resultado del While como abrir comentarios de cada publicación.
muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para realizar lo que estás comentando, crear mediante PHP los "Clic para mostrar comentarios", no es necesario poner el javascript dentro del while.

Crea primero los divs con su información.

```
<?php
while ($rowMP = $sqlMP->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<i id="'.$id.'" class="show-comments">...</i>';
    echo '<div class="comments" data-id-target="'.$id.'">...</div>';
}
?>
```

Ahora, con JQuery, puedes hacer clic sobre la clase "show-comments", recoger el id, y la clase que contenga el atributo data-id-target = id, lo muestras.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show-comments").on("click", function() {
        let id = $(this).attr("id")
        $(".comments").each(function() {
            if($(this).attr("data-id-target") == id) {
                $(this).show()
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Solo tienes que adaptarlo con las id's, clases, que más te convengan.

Comment: Wooo muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho, la verdad me toca dedicarme a estudiar mucho y mejorar, hasta ahora apenas estoy encaminándome en el mundo de la programación. 

Comment: De nada, recuerda si la respuesta resolvió tu duda, márcala como respuesta correcta 

Comment: Hola Zander tengo otra pregunta como le asigno el id al botón cerrar le coloque esta misma función, pero no me da, perdón lo inexperto...

Comment: Ya lo resolví muchas gracias Zander, estaba confundiendo el otro código 